# Name for a function that depends on time passed?

Tags: naming-conventions, scheduled-tasks

I currently have a function `updatePlayerData` which has as input a player object and the time that has passed since the last call to the function, and performs actions like `energy -= energyDecrease * time` on the player object .

I find the name for this function too vague and want to give it a better one, but don't know what the commonly accepted term for such a function is. Is there one?

(It's not *periodic* because the delta time is not constant)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly syncPlayer might be good or some variation of "synchronize" and "player".

Answer (score 0):

Call it `updatePlayer`. It's the `Data` which is vague.

Comment: I agree `Data` is a generic word without added value, but just `updatePlayer` is not that much more specific.

Comment: I think anyone having a little experience with games or games-programming will understand what your method does. At least I would not complain about your method name ;). `step` or `simulate` come to my mind as well.